# vb table adapter does not allow more than one parameter in the IN clause

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, tableadapter

What I need to achieve is to send a list of unknown QTY of values to a Sql server NOT IN clause but can only achieve this with singular values. below is my Sql statement:

```
SELECT        SorMaster.LastInvoice
            , SorMaster.SalesOrder
            , SorMaster.OrderStatus
            , ArCustomer.RouteCode
            , SorMaster.Customer
            , SorMaster.CustomerName
            , SorMaster.CustomerPoNumber
            , SorMaster.OrderDate
            , SorMaster.DateLastInvPrt
            , ArInvoice.InvoiceBal1
            , ArInvoice.TermsCode
FROM        SorMaster AS SorMaster 
INNER JOIN  ArCustomer AS ArCustomer ON SorMaster.Customer = ArCustomer.Customer 
INNER JOIN  ArInvoice AS ArInvoice ON SorMaster.LastInvoice = ArInvoice.Invoice
WHERE  (SorMaster.OrderStatus = '9') 
  AND (SorMaster.Branch LIKE 'J%') 
  AND (SorMaster.DocumentType = 'O') 
  AND (SorMaster.LastInvoice > @Last_Invoice) 
  AND (SorMaster.OrderDate > DATEADD(Month, - 4, GETDATE())) 
  AND (SorMaster.LastInvoice NOT IN (@ExclusionList))
ORDER BY SorMaster.LastInvoice
```

The @ExclusionList value is generated by this code as a string from a listbox:

```
Dim exclusion As String = ""
            If MenuForm.ExclusionCB.Checked = True Then
                For i = 0 To MenuForm.ExclusionLB.Items.Count - 2
                    exclusion = exclusion & MenuForm.ExclusionLB.Items(i) & ","
                Next
                exclusion = exclusion & MenuForm.ExclusionLB.Items(MenuForm.ExclusionLB.Items.Count - 1)
            Else
                exclusion = ""
            End If
```

I have also tried sending the entire listbox as a collection.

Does anyone know how I can send more than one value (something like 1,2,3,4,5,6) and have sql understand that these is more than one? I won't have an issue with the SELECT statement changing, just as long as it returns the same information.

The reason I need this with the exception list, is our remote DB PK is on the Salesorder column and the local DB is on the LastInvoice column

Hope this makes sense. if you need more info, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it as a string and use dynamic sql. Here's a simple example how to do that.

```
DECLARE @vals VARCHAR(50) = '1,2,3,4,5,6'
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD1 IN'

SET @sql = @sql + ' (' + @vals + ')'
-- @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD1 IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but to no avail. The Table Adapter does not support the 'declare' statement. Or should this be set as a stored procedure?

Comment: @StevendeBeer Huh? The declare statement is in your db stored proc. You just pass the parameter string '1,2,3,4,5,6' and append it.

Comment: I have no idea how to check stored procs on vs or howcto implement them.

Comment: @StevendeBeer where is that sql statement then? If you're calling to the db from code and hitting that statement, isn't that in a store proc?

Comment: I use the table adapter wizard to connect to my database and edit the call statement to get the info i need.

Comment: @StevendeBeer where is your call statement? I just see the sql and the loop to build the string

Comment: `Me.SorMasterTableAdapter.Fill(Me.InvoicesFDataSet.SorMaster,                                                           lookup, exclusion)`

Comment: I found a workaround by creating 10 parameters and instead of building a string, save the exclusion listbox contents into an array. and adding each array item into each parameter of the fill statement. all empty array items are autocreated as "0". this seems to work but looks a bit messy.

Comment: I found what you meant. In the table adapter properties, there is a command type that can be changed to run the command as a stored proc. I will keep this in mind for future reference. You really helped me a lot.

Comment: @StevendeBeer Glad I could help some. It's best practice to keep your sql and code separate. It's much cleaner and so much easier to debug.